# Ayuda para investigacion genealogía

Tags: genealogía

[image]Es la línea, señalada,nombre y apellido de un antepasado.

Comment: El único modo de descifrar lo que solicitas es comparando con otros caracteres similares, si no pones el documento entero es imposible hacer nada.

Comment: Lo que indica Diego parece plausible: "Encarnación Reyes". Si en el texto aparece otra n de esas sobresaliente en otra palabra terminada en "ción" puede darte la clave.

Comment: Gracias por eso ayuda. Ahora que lo han mencionado he visto más claramente el nombre.

Answer (score 2):

Es una forma peculiar y antigua de escribir nombres y palabras. Yo leo "**Encarnación Reyes**". Encarna es el nombre hipocorístico de Encarnación, pero la "n" que sobresale por arriba lo determina. Es como Mª que aparece más abajo refiriéndose a alguien llamado María, aunque en este caso estamos más acostumbrados a verlo.